# htaccess redirect for url with query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I want to redirct this url http://www.example.com/tev/?user-register=registered
to the home page http://www.example.com/

I have the following code in my htaccess file but it isn't working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^user-register=registered$
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^user-register=registered$
RewriteRule ^tev/?$ http://www.example.com/? [NC,R=301,L]
```